# What was Adi Shankara's view on Puranas?

Tags: puranas, history, vedanta, adi-shankaracharya

Puranas are the scriptures of Hinduism which are accepted by some people and rejected by some people. There are 18 Mahapuranas which are the most important. The basic theory that puranas are interpolated or not written by Sage Vyasa arises because many verses of Puranas contradict each other. Vishnu Purana says Lord Vishnu is supreme and other Devas are His subordinates and the same Shiva Mahapurana says that Lord Shiva is supreme and other devas are His subordinates (Same thing in Devi Purana etc).
Some Puranic stories also contradict other but to defend these puranas the theory is that the contradiction is arised due to Kalpa-Bheda. It could be true also.

**Now I want to know what did Adi Shankara thought about Puranas? He mainly wrote a commentary on Upanishads and Bhagavad Gita, did he mention anything about Puranas? Are Puranas authentic according to Shankara?**

Comment: The period at which Sri Sankara existed itself is in dispute.  Some say it was 509–477 BCE and some others say it was around 700 – c. 750 CE .  And, most of the texts that were attributed to  Adi Shankara and are likely to be works of his admirers or scholars (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara ).  So how can we make sure that his observations on Puranas are from his own writings?@Karmanya Nanda

Comment: You may this useful: http://www.advaita-vedanta.in/references-adi-shankara-vishnu-sahasranama-bhashya

Answer (score 3):

According to Shankaracharya Puranas are authentic, but the Puranas mentioned in Upanishads refer to Brahmana portion of the Vedas as per his Upanishadic Bhasya.

- As from a fire kindled with wet faggot diverse kinds of smoke issue,
  even so, my dear, the Ṛg-Veda, Yajur-Veda, Sāma-Veda, Atharvāṅgirasa,
  **History(Epics), Mythology(Puranas)**, arts, Upaniṣads, verses, aphorisms, elucidations and explanations are like the breath of this
  infinite Reality. They are like the breath of this Supreme Self.
  (Brihadaranyaka Up 2.4.10)

> Acharya Comments " **History, such as the dialogue between Urvaśī and
> Purūravas—‘The nymph Urvaśī,’ and so on (Ś. XI. iv. 4. 1); it is this
> Brāhmaṇa that is meant. Mythology, such as, ‘This universe was in the
> beginning unmanifest,’ etc. (Tai. II. 7)** "

- Then, its Northward rays are its northern honey-cells :- The
  Atharvangirasas are the honey-producers ;-the **Itihasa-Purana** are the
  flower :-those waters are the nectar.These Atharvagirasas pressed
  this Itihasa-Purana : from it, thus pressed, proceeded its essence in
  the form of fame, replendence, efficient organs, strength and eatable
  food. (Chandogya Up 3.4.1-2)

> Acharya comments "Itihasa-Purana are the flowers ;-the use of
> **Itihasa-Purana is well-known as to be made as part of the 'Pariplava Nights' at the Ashwamedha sacrifice.**

Comment: He has extensively cited Puranas in his shlokas and the bhashya of vishnu sahasranama. Therefore, it can be considered he did believe they were authentic.

Comment: Yeah sir but Puranas and Itihasas referred in Upanishads mean Brahmanas of Vedas not Vishnu Bhagavata Skanda Puranas as per Acharya Shankara. @GIRIBLR

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @SethuSrivatsa do you know about those Vishnu sahasranama shlokas which GIRIBLR is saying? it will make a good answer better. A small 2-3 line example maybe?

Comment: I didnt understad @Archit , should I quote his Vishnu Sahasranama Bhasya to say that he accepts Puranas?

Comment: @Archit What I meant was that Shankara quotes vishnu purana, brahma purana, skanda purana,  ramayana, mahabharata etc. in his vishnu sahasranama bhashya. As he has quoted from them, he believes them to be authentic.

Comment: @GIRIBLR yes understood :) hence I was suggesting that if he puts it the answer will look complete in the sense that yes Adi Shankara considers them authentic. Sethu

Comment: Vishnu purana is cited in 10, 96,406,456,557,574,558,659,753,907 and several more verses of the vishnu sahasranama.