# Did adi shankara accept purans as a valid source of information/knowledge?

Tags: puranas, adi-shankaracharya

Did adi shankara accept purans as a valid source of information/knowledge?

If not why did he rejected the Puranas because they are also [divine in origin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44506/22556)?

Comment: Adi Shankara is supposed to have read the Suta Samhita of the Skanda Purāṇa 18 times before writing a commentary one of the works like either Upanishad or Brahmasutra or so.

Comment: @hanugm there is no answer to it.

Comment: @DarkKnight Yeah, just kept for moderators attention...

Comment: Well Puranas are mentioned as 5th Veda in Upanishads. Shankara thinks Puranas as part of Brahmanas in his Upanishadic Bhasya not these Vishnu Skanda etc. Writing this here wont answer your Qn and will yield only downvotes. Hence I commented. What do you say

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru can you gave reffence to what you have said. And can you answer it that question

Comment: It will result in downvotes and deletions because Shankara thinks Puranas in Upanishads are devine but they refer to Brahmanas. SHall I proceed ? @DarkKnight

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru I don't think you can answer it on the duplicate question, no one has answered it.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru I ma asking purans like shiv purans, vishnu puran. And not the storyes mentioned in the upanishads

Comment: Puranas as per Upanishads and Shankara Bhasya in Upanishads dont refer to Vishnu and Shiva Puranas. I am writing answer to both qns @DarkKnight

Comment: Check this @DarkKnight https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/46206/19211

Comment: @DarkKnight  See whether the following answer is acceptable. As you are asking from vishnu purana etc. and not the incidents mentioned in the upanishads. If so, kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Adi shankaracharya accepts puranas as valid sources of information/knowledge.

Adi shankaracharya mentioned verses from vishnu Purana in Gita bhashya. For example -

> ।।3.37।। ऐश्वर्यस्य समग्रस्य धर्मस्य यशसः श्रियः। वैराग्यस्याथ मोक्षस्य षण्णां भग इतीरणा (**विष्णु पु** 6।5।74) ऐश्वर्यादिषट्कं यस्मिन् वासुदेवे नित्यमप्रतिबद्धत्वेन सामस्त्येन च वर्तते उत्पत्तिं प्रलयं चैव भूतानामागतिं गतिम्। वेत्ति विद्यामविद्यां च स वाच्यो भगवानिति (**विष्णु  पु** 6।5।78) उत्पत्त्यादिविषयं च विज्ञानं यस्य स वासुदेवः वाच्यः भगवान् इति।।

[Translation by Swami Gambhirananda](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=3&field_nsutra_value=36&setgb=1)

> 'Bhaga is said to consist of all kinds of majesty, virtue, fame, beauty, detachment as well as Liberation [Liberation stands for its cause, Illumination.], **(Vishnu.Purana.6.5.74)**. That Vasudeva, in whom reside for ever, unimpeded and in their fullness, the six alities of majesty etc. and who has the knowledge of such subjects as creation etc., is called Bhaga-van. 'He is spoken of as Bhaga-van who is aware of creation and dissolution, gain and loss, [Gain and loss stand for future prosperity and adversity.] ignorance and Illumination of all beings' **(Vishnu.Purana.6.5.78)**.

And in Brahma sutra bhashya Lord Adi shankaracharya tells that sudras are qualified to read Puranas and epics to gain knowledge.

[Brahma Sutra Bhashya 1.3.38](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34107.htm)

> Smriti, moreover, declares that **all the four castes are qualified for acquiring the knowledge of the itihâsas and purânas**; compare the passage, 'He is to teach the four castes' (Mahabharata)

In addition, Vishnu purana is cited in verses 10, 96,406,456,557,574,558,659,753,907 and several more verses in the Adi Shankara bhashya of the vishnu sahasranama. Other puranas such as linga purana and garuda purana are also cited in the bhashya of the vishnu sahasranama,